# Proof of an Infimum of a Subset

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $B$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $B\neq\emptyset$ is bounded from below. For $y\in\mathbb{R}$, $y-\frac{1}{n}$ is a lower bound of $B$, but $y+\frac{1}{n}$ is not a lower bound of $B$, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Show that $\inf B=y$.

Comment: Assume y is not an infimum.

Answer (score 1):

I have attempted to answer this, but I got stuck in the middle. Since $B$ is bounded from below and, if $y\in\mathbb{R}$, then $y-\frac{1}{n}$ is a lower bound of $B$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $\forall_{b\in B},b\geq y-\frac{1}{n}$. However, $y+\frac{1}{n}$ is not a lower bound of $B$ so it is safe to say $\forall_{b\in B},b<y+\frac{1}{n}$. Thus, we have discovered that $\forall_{b\in B},y-\frac{1}{n}\leq b<y+\frac{1}{n}$. How should I continue this?

Comment: What you have claimed is actually false. The fact that $y+1/n$ is not a lower bound of $B$ can only allow you to conclude that there exists some $b \in B$ such that $b \leq y+1/n$, not that you have this for all $b \in B$. Often, when you want to show that something is the infimum of a set, you first show that it is a lower bound to every element of the set, and then you show that there are no larger numbers that are also lower bounds to the set.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for pointing out where I made a mistake, but I am still confused about how I should show that if $y\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\forall_{b\in B},b\geq y$ and $y+\varepsilon$ is not a lower bound of $B$. I have no idea what to do with what has been given in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

$B$ is bounded from below, so it has a greatest lower bound.  Is it possible for the GLB to be less than $y$?  Can it be greater than $y$?